# Instanciando objeto de uma classe em um Input

Tags: python

Estou tentando fazer um programa em python com as duas classes: Disciplina e Sala, em um certo ponto quero relacionar a sala cadastrada na classe Sala na classe Disciplina, o código não gera erro, mas no final a sala não fica vinculada

```
class Sala:
    def __init__(self, numero):
        self.numero = numero
        self.andar = self.setAndar(numero)
        self.capacidade = None

    def setAndar(self, numero):
        self.andar = numero[0]
        return self.andar

    def set_capacidade(self, capacidade):
        self.capacidade = capacidade

    def get_sala(self):
        return self.numero

    def set_sala(self, sala):
        self.numero = sala

    def __str__(self):
        return "Sala: "+self.numero+" Andar: "+str(self.andar)+" Capacidade: "+self.capacidade

class Disciplina:
    def __init__(self, nome, semestre):
        self.nome = nome
        self.semestre = semestre
        self.sala = None

    def set_sala(self, sala):
        self.sala = sala

    def get_sala(self):
        if self.sala is None:
            return "Não definida!"
        if self.sala is not None:
            return self.sala

    def __str__(self):
        return "Disciplina: "+self.nome+" Semestre: "+self.semestre+" Sala : "+str(self.get_sala())


def relacionar_salas():

    imprime_disciplina()
    escolha_disciplina = input("Qual a disciplina gostaria de vincular a sala? ")
    objeto_discplina = classeDisciplina.Disciplina(escolha_disciplina, None)
    relatorio_salas()
    escolha_sala = input("A qual Sala? ")
    objeto_sala = classeDisciplina.Disciplina(escolha_sala, None)
    if escolha_disciplina not in lst_disciplina:
        print("Isso nao existe")
    else:
        objeto_discplina.set_sala(objeto_sala)
```

Comment: Por que o `objeto_sala` é uma instância da classe `Disciplina`?

Comment: Uma boa resposta a essa pergunta teria que passar por um monte de conceitos - teria que ser praticamente uma aula (bem dada) de uso de orientação a objetos.

Um lugar onde talvez a mescla de "como criar objetos relacionados" esteja bem explicado pode ser o tutorial de frameworks como o Django, que mapeiam diretamente para tabelas relacionadas.  

Sugiro que você leia o tutorial do Django - a parte de "modelos" -mesmo que nesse momento não pretenda fazer a sua aplicação pra web. https://django-portuguese.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/intro/tutorial01.html  - -

Comment: Mas aviso - você está com dúvidas mais básicas de programação, a partir do exemplo do código que deu - praticament eescrevendo chamadas aleatórias a funções, etc... pode ser que tenha qu fazer exercícios mais básicos antes de progredir para onde quer chegar.

Comment: Vale a pena dar uma olhada nesse [artigo](https://www.alura.com.br/artigos/como-comparar-objetos-no-python), deve dar a solução.

Answer (score -1):

Olá,

Primeiro é muito importante escolher bons nomes para funções. Se o objetivo da função é relacionar uma sala a uma disciplina, sugiro o nome `relaciona_sala_disciplina()`. Parece bobagem mas um bom nome ajuda a saber o que uma função faz e qual é o objetivo dela.

Outro ponto é que uma função deve ter uma única responsabilidade, portanto se o objetivo dela é relacionar uma sala à uma disciplina, não compete a ela criar uma sala ou uma disciplina, porque o objetivo dela não é esse. Esse é o primeiro princípio da SOLID e se aplica classes mas funciona muito bem com funções também. Sugiro que veja este excelente vídeo [SOLID](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mkx0CdWiPRA).

Vamos ao código. Primeiramente eu modifiquei os magic methods `__str__()` de cada classe de

```
class Sala:
# ... varias linhas de código
   
    def __str__(self):
        return "Sala: "+self.numero+" Andar: "+str(self.andar)+" Capacidade: "+self.capacidade


class Disciplina:
# ... varias linhas de código

    def __str__(self):
        return "Disciplina: "+self.nome+" Semestre: "+self.semestre+" Sala: "+str(self.get_sala())

# ... varias linhas de código
```

para :

```
class Sala:
# ... varias linhas de código
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Sala: {self.numero}  Andar: {self.andar}  Capacidade: {self.capacidade}"


class Disciplina:
# ... varias linhas de código

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Disciplina: {self.nome}  Semestre: {self.semestre} Sala: {self.sala}"

# ... varias linhas de código
```

Desta forma o print de cada classe fica igual, mas dentro do método `__str__` fica mais legível.

A primeira modificação que eu fiz na função `relacionar_salas()` foi renomear ela para `relaciona_sala_disciplina()`.

```
disciplinas_disponiveis = ['matemática', 'física', 'química', 'biologia']

def relaciona_sala_disciplina():
    print(disciplinas_disponiveis)

    disciplina_escolhida = input("Qual a disciplina gostaria de vincular a sala? ")
    discplina = Disciplina(disciplina_escolhida, None)

    sala_escolhida = input("A qual Sala? ")
    sala = Sala(sala_escolhida)

    if disciplina_escolhida not in disciplinas_disponiveis:
        print("Isso nao existe")
    else:
        discplina.set_sala(sala.numero)
        return sala, discplina


sala_qualquer, disciplina_qualquer = relaciona_sala_disciplina()

print(sala_qualquer)
print(disciplina_qualquer)
```

Sequencialmente o processo que será realizado é a exibição das disciplinas disponíveis (*criei esta lista `disciplina_disponíveis` só pra simular a sua função `imprime_disciplina()`*). Também fiz outras renomeações por exemplo `objeto_sala` para simplesmente `sala`. Mas no fim esta função vai criar dois objetos quaisquer, um do tipo `Sala` e outro do tipo `Disciplina`.

Ao rodar este código com as devidas substituições que eu cheguei neste output:

```
['matemática', 'física', 'química', 'biologia']
Qual a disciplina gostaria de vincular a sala? física
A qual Sala? 42
Sala: 42  Andar: 4  Capacidade: None
Disciplina: física   Semestre: None  Sala: 42
```

Espero muito que eu tenha conseguido te ajudar. Qualquer dúvida não hesite em perguntar.

Até mais!